# ExtJs 4 Combobox missing config option hiddenName

Tags: forms, extjs, combobox, extjs4

I'm trying to create an ExtJs version 4 ComboBox that will post the valueField and not the displayValue.  Prior version would be to set the 'hiddenName' option in the config of ComboBox, but I can't seem to find it in v 4 or something equivalent.  Also, this is NOT in an ExtJs form panel.  The combobox is being rendered inside a plain html form

```
//My Code

new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    renderTo: 'my_div',
    store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        fields: ['value', 'name'],
        data: [['1', 'A'], ['2', 'B'], ['3', 'C']]
    }),
    name: 'letter',
    hiddenName: 'letter_id',
    hiddenValue : '0',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'value',
    mode: 'local'
});



//  The value of the form POST when I selected 'A'
"letter=A"

//  This is what I want
"letter=1"
```

Comment: i think the problem is `The combobox is being rendered inside a plain html form` combobox in Extjs is different with `<select>` tag in plain html

Answer (score 2):

just for info.... Extjs team has improved the "configs" for every element.
And in `combobox` there is no longer `hiddenName`
have you ever read [this](http://www.slideshare.net/edspencer/intro-to-ext-4)? try to navigate to page 52, both will yield similar results...

```
var itemForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.FormPanel',{
    title: 'Simple Form',
    renderTo :Ext.getBody(),
    url :'test.php',
    items:[
        new Ext.form.ComboBox({
            store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
                fields: ['value', 'name'],
                data: [['1', 'A'], ['2', 'B'], ['3', 'C']]
            }),
            name: 'letter',
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'value',
        })]
});
```

when i run this `itemForm.getForm().submit()` it send `letter = 1`..
maybe the error is somewhere else ..

Answer (score 0):

After stuck 8 hours i found problem my store respond from server contain "\r" or "\n"
Just remove it it will work fine :)