# How do i submit the fieldValue of a combobox in Extjs 4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm using Extjs 4.0.7 and having a hard time getting a `combobox` in a `formPanel` to `submit` the `fieldValue` of the selected option on the `combobox`.

As far as I can tell this is normally achieved by setting the `hiddenName` configuration option to a value you want it to submit the value as; like using a hidden field in html, but the `hiddenName` option now seems to be removed from the docs, without any obvious alternatives.

So how do I go on about submitting my `formPanel` with the value of the `valueField` in Extjs 4?

This is a snip from my application, where I define one of the comboboxes:

```
xtype: 'combobox',
        name: 'shift',
        hiddenName: 'shiftid',
        id: 'shiftCombobox',
        fieldLabel: 'Shift',
        labelWidth: 30,
        width: 130,
        margin: '0 5',
        cls: 'shift',
        store: shiftStore, 
        autoSelect: true,
        queryMode: 'local',
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'objectid',
        autoSelect: true,
        handler: function() {
            //changeShift(); 
        }
```

and this is the model which the `shiftStore` uses:

```
Ext.define('shiftModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'objectid', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
    ]
});
```

Comment: I found the solution, but can't answer my own question yet. Feel free to post a solid way to control which gets submitted though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5724225/6294 has the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten about this code:

```
autoLoad: {
        //The callback here is needed to fix a bug and set a default value in the combobox. 
        scope: this,
        callback: function() {
            var comboBox = Ext.getCmp("teamCombobox");
            var store = comboBox.store;

            // set the value of the comboBox here
            comboBox.setValue(store.getAt('0').get('name'));
        }
    }
```

Which updates the `combobox` on the `combobox`'s stores `autoLoad`, to use a default value on load. 
I had set the value to *name* which is the `displayValue`. Setting the value to the corresponding `fieldValue`, in my case a field called *objectid*

After I set it like this, it works:

```
comboBox.setValue(store.getAt('0').get('objectid'));
```

Now the `combox` submits it's real `fieldValue` instead of the textual value I accidentally set.

I'd still like to know if there is some way to control this though.